# Qt and MOC woes with a simple make

Tags: qt, makefile, gnu-make

I guess this is more of a GNU Make question than Qt and moc, but here goes.

I have a directory which contains multiple `Q_OBJECTS`, and I have some simple code, which collects all these, e.g

```
MOCS := $(shell grep -l Q_OBJECT $(HEADERS))
```

Assume `HEADERS` is a collection of the header files in the "current location"

Now what I would like to do is specify a rule which will call Qt moc to build the .C file and then compile that into an object. How would one specify such a rule?

My starting point is dumb:

```
MOC_SOURCES := $(MOCS:%.h=%.C)
MOC_OBJECTS := $(MOC_SOURCES:%.C=%.o)

$(MOC_SOURCES) : $(MOCS)
  @echo "Building Moc: $@ from $<"
  $(MOC) $< -o $@
```

This is dumb because, what is happening is that `$<` the first header, and so all the objects are compiled using this header rather than the related headers.

Is there a way to clean this up so that the correct moc object is built from the correct header?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you doing this instead of getting `qmake` to build it for you?

Comment: @cmannett85 I must admit, I've not heard of this. However, the problem is that the GUI components are a small part of a much larger library, which is built using gnu make.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To produce each `$(MOCS_SOURCES)` component from each `$(MOC)` component, you may use a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-versus-Implicit.html#Static-versus-Implic), like this:

```
$(MOC_SOURCES) : %.C: %.h
    @echo "Building Moc: $@ from $<"
    $(MOC) $< -o $@
```

Another common practice is to use implicit rules, but with a specific suffix for C++ files produced by `moc`. Here's what I use when qmake is not an option:

```
%.moc.o: %.moc.cpp
    $(CXXCOMPILE) $(QT_CPPFLAGS) $(QT_CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.moc.cpp: %.h
    $(MOC) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the latter hint was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about QT or moc, but if what you're saying is that moc is a tool that takes a single header file and generates a single `.C` file, then you can just use a pattern rule:

```
%.C : %.h
        $(MOC) $< -o $@
```