# How to get my makefile-based C++ project to work with QT library shortest and simplest way?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have an **Makefile**-based C++ project.
I use **Eclipse** as and IDE (on Ubuntu) and it works perfectly with Makefile. I write Makefile myself by hand, so I don't need any things that can generate it automatically.

I heard that **QT** uses its own `qmake` buld system, which makes Makefile from .pro project file:

> In addition to Qt Creator, Qt provides qmake, a cross-platform build script generation tool that automates the generation of Makefiles for development projects across different platforms.

Eclipse QT plugin description says:

> The Qt Eclipse Integration seamlessly integrates the whole Qt development workflow:
>   Pure qmake based project management (not imposing Eclipse specific project file formats) with a .pro file importer and graphical project editor

It seems like if I want to use Qt, it absolutely has to use its own  `qmake` build system, which will be generating makefiles. I don't like that idea because my Makefiles are too complex, I don't want to put a lot of effort to figuring out how to translate my whole Makefile to .pro file or similar.

1. Is there any way to use Qt just like any other library, installing it into system, including header files in my code and giving a linker path to include it? Without changing whole build system, i.e. sticking with manually edited makefile and not using QtEditor, but Eclipse as before? I don't need any GUI-related Qt stuff.
2. Do I absolutely have to use `qmake`? Can I just use `make` command only as before?

Comment: I believe you can use Qt library in the same way as you use other C++ libraries with your existing Makefiles. However to make Qt's signal/slots working you have to write additional rules to process moc headers. There are plenty of examples. For example here: https://gist.github.com/mishurov/8134532  or https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330017/2674506 .

Comment: You can have a `Makefile` in the source directory that runs `qmake` on `project.pro`, and then runs  `make` on the `Makefile` in `qmake`'s output directory

Comment: @Caleth [doc.qt.io](http://doc.qt.io) says `project files will use a straightforward declarative style, defining standard variables to indicate the source and header files that are used in the project`. So `project.pro` would contain info about source code files, but it's already in my existing `Makefile`. I have to write .pro myself based on a makefile? What's the point to keep original Makefile then?

Comment: As an example: You have `my_gui_class.hpp`, `my_gui_class.cpp`, and `my_gui_form.ui` In `project.pro`, you list those in appropriate sections. When you run `qmake`, it will generate a `Makefile` that has rules like `my_gui_class_moc.cpp : moc my_gui_class.hpp` which will generate the string tables etc needed for signals and slots, `ui_my_gui_form.h : uic my_gui_form.ui` which will generate a `QWidget` based form class. `my_gui_class.cpp` refers to `ui_my_gui_form.h`, even though that file is a build artefact (isn't committed in source control, will die to `make clean`, etc)

Comment: @Caleth thanks. And I have a bunch of other files, which don't use `Qt`, legacy simple C++ code, where do they go? I have to put 'em in `project.pro` as well, or they can be somehow in another `Makefile`, which (may be) can refer to qmake`s `Makefile`?

Comment: In your handcrafted `Makefile`, you add the "to be generated" `.cpp` and `.h` files as dependencies of the final executable, with a build step like `qmake project.pro` `make -C generated_dir/ $(1)`

Comment: I'd be happier to see just additional rules for moc headers/resources than a `*.pro` with `qmake` attached to the makefile build.

Comment: @vahancho Write your comment as an answer and I will accept that. Your first example saved my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use Qt library in the same way as you use other C++ libraries with your existing Makefiles. You just have to treat any Qt application or library as a regular C++ application or library with its specific dependencies.

However Qt's signal/slot functionality requires generation of some extra code with Qt's moc utility. This is especially true for Qt4 projects and if you use "traditional" macros based signals/slots connections. So you have to write additional rules in your Makefiles to process moc headers. There are plenty of examples on how to do that. For example: [this](https://gist.github.com/mishurov/8134532) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330017/2674506).